# No funciona el método POST para conectar mi plantilla de Vue con la plantilla de Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

no sé como conectar mi plantilla de Vue con el método POST, lo he conseguido con el método GET, sé que la URL de la api de laravel funciona, pues las pruebas echas en PostMan me lo devuelven correctamente, así que sé que tiene que ser en enlace hecho desde vue. Os paso el código de la página entera, especifíco que lo único que no funciona es efectivamente al intentar usar el método guardarComentario(). Gracias por adelantado!

```
<script>
 import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                
                listaComentarios: [
                    // { id: 25, user_id: 1, comentario: 'acabar vue' },
                    { id: 26, user_id: 2, comentario: 'prueba conexión' }
                ],
                user_id: '',
                comentario: '',
                snackbar: false,
                mensaje: '',
                formAgregar: true,
                indexTarea: ''

            }
        },

    methods: {
        agregarComentario() {
            if (this.comentario === '') {
                this.snackbar = true
                this.mensaje = 'El usuario o el comentario están vacíos'
            } else {
                this.listaComentarios.push({
                    id: this.id,
                    comentario: this.comentario
                })
                this.user_id = 1
                this.comentario = ''
                this.snackbar = true
                this.mensaje = 'Comentario añadido :)'
            }
        }, 
        guardarComentario() {
            axios.post("127.0.0.1:8000/api/comentarios/" + this.comentario.id)
            .then(results => this.comentario = results.data.id);
            console.log(this.comentario.id);
            this.snackbar = true
            this.mensaje = 'Ahora todo el mundo puede ver tu comentario :)'

        }
    },
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: Y que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Hola @b28 . Cuando envías el comentario, por qué añades el "127.0.0.1:8000"? en principio laravel, ya detecta que esa ruta pertenece al archivo api.php que es donde almacenas todas las rutas de tu CRUD